# Eclipse Formatter: Wrap Nested ArrayList Declarations

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, spring-tool-suite

I have a rather large and annoying nest of parameterized classes, such as the following for example:

```
HashMap<ExampleClass, ArrayList<ArrayList<ADifferentClass>>> PITA_var = new HashMap<ExampleClass, ArrayList<ArrayList<ADifferentClass>>>();
```

As you can see, declaring variables that utilize this nested ArrayList is a pain, especially when the declaration extends off-screen. I would like to have Eclipse (okay technically I'm using STS) at least solve that problem, but I have been unable to determine how to do so. Any help?

PS I know it would be a simple matter to declare additional classes that subclass these types; I am already doing that to an extent, and further subclassing would not be practical.

Comment: What version of Eclipse does your STS complies to?

Comment: The Eclipse platform is version 4.5.1, and the Java Development Tools version is 3.11.1

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Eclipse, so this answer may not be what you are looking for, but here are a few tips.

Firstly, use interfaces. That type should be

```
Map<ExampleClass, List<List<ADifferentClass>>>
```

Secondly, if you can, upgrade to Java 7 or 8. Then you can do:

```
 Map<ExampleClass, List<List<ADifferentClass>>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

> PS I know it would be a simple matter to declare additional classes that subclass these types; I am already doing that to an extent, and further subclassing would not be practical.

Do not do that. Using subclasses just to get rid of type parameters is considered an antipattern.

Finally, consider whether your design could be improved. There may be a better approach than having a `Map` where the values are `List`s of `List`s.

Comment: Hey look at that. Eclipse doesn't complain about the lack of parameterizeation. Anyways, I would still like to include the type parameters for readability if doing so is reasonable. I like the interface suggestion though; I have been migrating away from that lately, so it didn't even occur to me.